# How can I handle an attachment of an embedded message attachment?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am automatically processing emails in a certain inbox. However our suppliers should send emails to that inbox with one pdf-attachment. and this pdf-attachment should be saved to a certain folder - no problem so far.

But: one supplier is sending emails that only contain another email as attachment and only in that "sub-email" the pdf is to be found. For some reasons he is not able to change that.

Now it does not seem possible to use that attachment of the attachment as mailitem:

```
Set objMail_New = objMail_In.Attachments.Item(1)
```

neither could i forward the attachment to the same mail-address again (which would have brought me the mail that I needed in the first place):

```
Set objMail_Forw = objMail_In.Attachments.Item(1).forward
```

Both bring the error "type mismatch"

Anyone any other ideas? Maybe it is possible to save the (first) attachment locally and then handle it to get to the second attachment?

Thanks max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook does not allow to access embedded message attachments. The best you can do is save the attachment as an MSG file (`Attachment.SaveAsFile` - you will get an MSG file), then open it using `Namespace.OpenSharedItem` (returns `MailItem` object, so you can access its `Attachments` collection).

You can also use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) which allows to access embedded messages attachment using [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).`EmbeddedMsg`